# jQuery: How to add active selected menu class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have trouble with active class with this menu.

[image]

As you can see here, now active class is on all orders tab.

I want to active this this on each tab when i click on it with removing past tab's class.

HTML for this menu-

```
<ul id="mainSideMenu" class="nav nav-list nav-side" >
    <li class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading active ">
            <a href="#accDash" id="AllOrders" data-parent="#mainSideMenu"  data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle ">
                <span class="item-icon fontello-icon-monitor "></span><i class="chevron fontello-icon-right-open-3"></i>
                All Orders
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is active class-

```
.nav-side .accordion-group > .active {
    background: url("../img/background/body-bg-02.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

With jQuery i tried-

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordion-group").click(function(){
        $(".accordion-group").removeClass('.active').addClass('.active');
        $(this).addClass('.active');
    });
});
```

That was not happening

This is happening live here-
[Boo admin template](http://themeforest.net/item/boo-admin-responsive-template/full_screen_preview/3489498)

Comment: Could you possibly make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the leading dot in `addClass` and `removeClass`.
And why do you add back the active class in the 2nd line? Remove that part.
And you are adding the class to the heading, not the group?

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordion-group").click(function(){
        $(".accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.accordion-heading').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Even removing dot from addClass and second line not solving this, Maybe some path problem there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your `.accordion-group` that has the `active` class so that's not where you need to add and remove it. Furthermore, you should add and remove a class named `active`, not `.active`.

It also seems that you are currently re-adding the active class immediately after you've removed it, which is in error.

```
$(function(){
   $(".accordion-group").click(function(){
      $(".accordion-group .active").removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-heading', this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".accordion-group").removeClass('active').addClass('active');
```

classname is enough.Remove `.` before class name

Answer (score 0):

Remove .from class name

```
$(function(){
$(".accordion-group").click(function(){
$(".accordion-group").removeClass('active').addClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

remove `.`

read more about [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="ulVertical">
        <li id="firstLink" class="vertical-selected-li">My First Link</li>
        <li id="secondLink" class="">My Second List</li>
        <
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#secondLink").click(function () {

    $(this).siblings().removeClass('vertical-selected-li');
    $(this).addClass('vertical-selected-li');

    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be an accordion plugin I think the click is catched by the "a" and not propaged to the li.accordion-group (that's why your code doesn't appear to be executed), did you try listening the event on the "a" instead of the "li" ?

something like

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordion-group .accordion-heading a").click(function(){
        $(".accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

btw, I would use the .on() method instead of the .click() :)